# How to install Mediawiki in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I am presently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I want to install Mediawiki.I followed below link commands but it showing as 'mediawiki' has no installation candidate. You can see it on picture.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MediaWiki
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: What is your end goal here? A private MediaWiki instance running on localhost?

Comment: Yes, I want to run on localhost.

Comment: Hey, I've looked through your profile and I've noticed you got some good answers, but haven't accepted anything. If an answer to any of your questions solved your problem, hit the grey checkmark by that answer. It'll turn green, and the answer will be marked "accepted", which gives you some reputation and lets others find the solution faster.

Answer (score 7):

The `mediawiki` package is no longer in the [Ubuntu repository for 16.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=mediawiki) for a number of reasons, so we're left with having to install it manually.

Your webserver is configured to serve to port 80 on `localhost` right now, with content from `/var/www/html`. So, if we just [install MediaWiki there](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installation_guide), it'll be good enough.

Essentially you're just going to need to `cd` over to that directory and download the latest version using the following command:

```
wget https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.27/mediawiki-1.27.1.tar.gz
```

Then, we can extract this archive:

```
tar xvf mediawiki-1.27.1.tar.gz
```

From there, you can just navigate to `http://localhost/mediawiki-1.27.1/` in your browser and then follow the instructions given there to set it up. If you prefer, you can rename the folder to just `mediawiki` if it makes it easier on you.

Comment: You will also need to install PHP, MySQL and a number of PHP modules,  and enable them, e.g. `apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-php7.0 php-apcu php-gd php-json php-mysql php-xml; phpenmod apcu gd json pdo_mysql dom; a2enmod php7.0`

Comment: okay, Now i want to use Mediawiki web page to save my personal files. I created an account in Mediawiki. How can i change my privacy. No one have to see my personal data.

Comment: @RindhuKondaparthy If you're running on `localhost` on a private server and port 80 isn't opened to LAN, it's only accessible to your network as a whole. If you want to have only your local computer access it, you can probably just block port 80 inbound using ufw.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more, or provide a link, to the *"number of reasons"* why the mediawiki package is no longer in the Ubuntu repository for 16.04. Very interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A newer version of MekiaWiki is available in 16.10 and you can follow the instructions [here](http://www.hiroom2.com/2016/08/05/ubuntu-16-04-install-mediawiki/) to install on 16.04. Note however that "mediawiki_1.27.0-1.*" are now "mediawiki_1.27.1-2*" at this time.